# Yolo model.save() function saves the detected images into seperate folders

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

Hello I'm trying to read frames from a file and detect each of them. Then store them inside an output folder. But what model does is, it creates different folders for each output image.

```
import os
import torch
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # yolov5n - yolov5x6 official model
#                                            'custom', 'path/to/best.pt')  # custom model
folderPath = r"C:\yolo\deneme\miniframes"
imageFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folderPath) if f.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]

output_folder_path = r"C:\yolo\deneme\detectedframes"
#os.makedirs(output_folder_path, exist_ok=True)

output_txt_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, "results.txt")

all_results = []

for frameNumber, image in enumerate(imageFiles):
    imagePath = os.path.join(folderPath, image)
    results = model(imagePath)
    results.save(save_dir = output_folder_path )

    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
    #print(df)

    for i in df['name']:  # name->labels
        all_results.append((frameNumber, i))

# Write results to text file
with open(output_txt_path, 'w') as f:
    for frameNumber, obj in all_results:
        f.write(f"Frame:{frameNumber} {obj}\n")
```

Here you can see how it saves the detected results into different folders:
[detected output frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojMlk.png)

Also here is the chatgpt solution but it didnt work:

```
 output_image_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"detected_{image}")
 results.save(save_dir=output_folder_path, save_img=True, img_format='jpg', img_name=f"detected_{image}")
```

I also tried to use model.predict function but it didn't work without using YOLO model directly by importing ultralytics. My yolov5s.pt is inside my project directory.

Edit: Here is the save function on yolov5s side ( yolov5s/common/models )

```
def save(self, labels=True, save_dir="runs/detect/exp", exist_ok=False):
    save_dir = increment_path(save_dir, exist_ok, mkdir=True)  # increment save_dir
    self._run(save=True, labels=labels, save_dir=save_dir)  # save results
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the optimal solution but I've solved it by putting them inside a temporary folder then moving. Finally deleting the temp folders. I am still waiting for better solutions.Here is the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import torch
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

model  = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  

folderPath = r"C:\yolo\deneme\miniframes"
imageFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folderPath) if 
f.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]

output_folder_path = r"C:\yolo\deneme\detectedframes"

output_txt_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, "results.txt")

all_results = []

for frameNumber, image in enumerate(imageFiles):
    imagePath = os.path.join(folderPath, image)

    results = model(imagePath)

    df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]

    for i in df['name']:  # name->labels
        all_results.append((frameNumber, i))



    output_image_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, 
f"detected_{frameNumber}")

    temp_save_dir = os.path.join(output_folder_path, "temp_save")
    results.save(save_dir = temp_save_dir )


    for file in os.listdir(temp_save_dir):
        file_path = os.path.join(temp_save_dir, file)
        shutil.move(file_path, output_folder_path)

    os.rmdir(temp_save_dir)


with open(output_txt_path, 'w') as f:
    for frameNumber, obj in all_results:
        f.write(f"Frame:{frameNumber} {obj}\n")
```